# Excel: carregar lista de nomes de acordo com a seleção de outra lista

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, lista, planilha

na escola que trabalho tem um arquivo com as planilhas das turmas (o nome da planilha é o número da turma. Ex: 100, 200, ...).

Preciso fazer uma planilha neste mesmo arquivo para gerar Declarações, onde preciso selecionar a Turma, e feito isso carregar os nomes dos alunos. Selecionar o aluno e carregar os dados dele.

É possível fazer isso sem VBA (não sei VBA =[ )?

Eu consigo fazer a Declaração fixando os valores:

Ex: crio uma lista da turma 100, seleciono o aluno, e para ler a data de nascimento uso a fórmula:
=DESLOC('100'!$B$3;CORRESP(F14;'100'!$B$3:'100'!$B$52;0)-1;1;1)

O que eu preciso é que quando selecionar outra turma a referência da função mude para a turma selecionada (ao invés de 100, 200 por exemplo. Não precisa ser uma seleção, pode ser por exemplo o valor digitado em uma célula.

E seria possível também, após selecionar a turma (ou ler seu número de uma célula), alterar a lista de alunos? A validação de dados diz que não aceita fórmulas.

Comment: posso estar errado pois n sei muito de exel mais ao meu ver  e so fazer um monte de SE e Senão

Comment: Pois é romulo, quero simplificar hehe

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como está organizada sua planilha e os dados, mas olhando para a fórmula que você criou dá pra fazer assim:

```
=DESLOC(A1 !$B$3;CORRESP(F14; A1 !$B$3: A1 !$B$52;0)-1;1;1)
```

Dessa forma, se você colocar `100` na célula `A1` ele vai retornar os dados do aluno da turma `100`, se colocar `200` na célula `A1` vai retornar os alunos da turma `200` e assim por diante.

Sugiro que você dê uma estudada na fórmula [=Procv()](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/procv-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-procv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). Vai conseguir fazer o que deseja utilizando bem menos fórmulas e sem tanta complicação.

Para sua segunda dúvida é exatamente igual. Defina uma célula onde você colocará o código da turma e use um procv para retornar o nome, procv para retornar a idade, a nota, etc.

Caso não consiga faça uma nova pergunta informando o código que você tentou e uma imagem exemplificando a disposição dos dados.

Comment: Então Max, não funcionou dessa forma.

Os dados estão assim:

1) Arquivo 'turmas.xls'

2) 1 planilha para cada turma. O nome da planilha é o número da turma. Ex: 100, 200, ...

Os dados estão dispostos assim:

B1 - nome
B2 - nascimento
B3 - nome do pai
B4 - ...
Bx

3) 1 planilha de declaração

A1 - número da turma que quero tirar declaração

Ao digitar o número da turma e apertar 'enter' os dados da turma devem ser carregados da planilha correspondente.

Comment: Meu problema:

1º - a lista de alunos para selecionar

Minha lista está fixa. Exemplo com a turma 100: '=100!$B$1:$B$60'

2º - ao selecionar o aluno exibir as informacoes correspondentes

Exemplo para pegar a data de nascimento de um aluno da turma 100:

=DESLOC('100'!$B$3;CORRESP(A2;'100'!$B$1:'100'!$B$60;0)-1;1;1)

A2 é onde está a lista com nome do aluno.

A linha abaixo não funcionou:

=DESLOC(A1 !$B$1;CORRESP(A2; A1 !$B$1: A1 !$B$60;0)-1;1;1)

Comment: pessoal resolvi, usei INDIRETO